# Regex for 17 digits allowing spaces

Tags: android, regex, ocr

What may be the regex for allowing 17 digits with or without spaces in-between any number of the characters?
I am using a OCR real-time capture SDK (ABBYY RTR SDK) on Android(, and I'm using a custom data capture (which has to capture 17 digits with or without spaces in-between anywhere)

My regex is currently this:

```
field.setRegEx( "[0-9]{14,16}" );
```

This is only able to capture in-line digits (**38492039483726473**)

But I need it to capture digits in that format, as well as this format - **3849 20394 8372 6473**.
How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's simply those two formats:

```
(\d{17}|\d{4}\s\d{5}\s(?:\d{4}\s){2})
```

Captures a digit 17 times

or

Capture 4 digits followed by a space, then 5 digits followed by another space, and then 4 digits followed by a space twice

Comment: OP says: "What may be the regex for allowing 17 digits with or without spaces in-between any number of the characters?" your regex  works only for the specific example posted in the question, not for whitespaces in any place of the string.

Comment: @mrzasa That’s why I prefaced the answer with “If it’s simply for those two formats”. I would definitely recommend going for your answer, should there need to be more formats.

Comment: Sorry, I need to read whole answers, not only code examples :)

Comment: This is quite helpful. Though I noticed in the documentation of the OCR that it's regular expressions do not support specific characters. Using your answer I was able to capture the data in all the formats that I needed to capture. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Try repeating a digit with optional space:

```
(\d ?){17}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vzc9Gs/1/)

Comment: Great approach! I noticed the documentation said that some regex characters are not supported (My bad). I also noticed it's better if I use or statements in my regex to find the right formats that I need. In this case : **\d{17}|\d{4}\s\d{5}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}** would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the answer given by @mrzasa would be to first remove all whitespace from the number string, and then use a simpler regex to check for 17 digits:

```
String input = "3849 20394 8372 6473";
if (input.replaceAll("\\s+", "").matches("\\d{17}")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

Comment: This is a better option (unless you have to do it using one regexp).

Comment: @mrzasa I upvoted you, because you beat me to it, but yes, I also imagine that arbitrary whitespace in the number string would have to be stripped off anyway at some point.

Comment: This is a real-time capture. I don't have much control over the strings that it's currently capturing, I only have access to final captures ( which are in the case of the regex). But I understand how it could be a solution if  I had access to those strings.

Comment: @DeanEncoded Then the other regex answers can hopefully help you.